# Equivalence between different definition of winding numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, topology, topological-phase

At the moment I am reading the paper by A. Schynder and S. Ryu [arXiv: 1011.1438](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1438). The general setup is a superconductor with time-reversal symmetry. I can write my Bogoliubov - de Gennes in the following way:

$$
H_{\text{BdG}} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & D \\
D^{\dagger} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In the supplementary materials the definition for the winding number in one-dimensional Systems is given by

$$
\nu = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{1.BZ}dk\text{ Tr}\left(q^{-1}\partial_{k}q\right)
$$

where $q = \sum_{\alpha}\frac{1}{\lambda_{\alpha}}u_{\alpha}u_{\alpha}^{\dagger}D$, with $\Lambda_{\alpha}$ is the Eigenvalues of the Bogoliubov - de Gennes Hamiltonian and $u_{\alpha}$ is a component of the Nambu spinor. If the bands are degenerated then $q = \frac{D}{\lambda}$.

However, also in the supplementary matrials is an alternative Definition for the winding number

$$
\nu = \frac{1}{4\pi i}\int_{1.BZ}dk\text{ Tr}\left(D^{-1}\partial_{k}D - \left(D^{\dagger}\right)^{-1}\partial_{k}D^{\dagger}\right)
$$

Now I try to show the equivalence between both definitions. When I use the first definition and put into the definition for $q= \frac{D}{\lambda}$ (because I think if I will understand the easy case then the harder case will be work in the same way), then I obtain:

$$
\text{Tr}\left(q^{-1}\partial_{k}q\right) = \text{Tr}\left(D^{-1}\partial_{k}D - \frac{1}{\lambda}\partial_{k}\lambda\right)
$$

The first term is fine but the second term is not and I do not know how to Show the equivalence between both definitions (if there exist a equivalence).

Comment: Isn't it a symmetry of the $q$'s making them pure real or imaginary ? Or $q^{-1}\partial_{k}q$ ? Usually one works with unitary transformation and so one has instead $q^{\dagger}\partial_{k}q$ instead, in which case, since $q^{\dagger}q=1$, one has $\partial q^{\dagger}q+q^{\dagger}\partial q=0$ and because $\left(\partial q^{\dagger}q\right)^{\dagger}=q^{\dagger}\partial q$ the object $q^{\dagger}\partial q$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Ah ok, no I think it's something else : I think the first definition is for a Hamiltonian like $H\sim D$, here due to the symmetry of the BdG Hamiltonian, one takes $\nu\sim\Tr\left\{ \mathbf{i}\tau_{y}\mathcal{K}H^{-1}\partial H\right\}/2 $ with $\mathbf{i}\tau_{y}\mathcal{K}$ the time reversal operation. Applied to your $H$ it gives the second expression of $\nu$. So the first $\nu$ you give is the usual definition of a 1D winding number without symmetry, and the second one is for time-reversal symmetric systems.

Comment: More details there : http://topo-houches.pks.mpg.de/?page_id=369 Lecture by Bernevig at Les Houches Summer School: Topological aspects of condensed matter physics.

Comment: @FraSchelle thanks, but this means that there exist two definitions for the winding number. But it should be possible to show that both definitions will give the same result for the winding number.

Comment: Yes there are several *winding number*, depending on the context. Indeed, there are several *topological invariant*, regarding which system you have in mind. I asked about the question of the construction of topological invariant somewhere else on this website: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167055/16689. If I'm correct about your question here, the two $\nu$ you wrote are not isomorphic to each other. Did you check the lecture by Bernevig by the way ?

Comment: I just read the lecture notes. Corresponding Video I will watch later. In the notes it is written "In odd dimensions of space, we can deﬁne an alternative topological invariant for systems
with chiral symmetry (...)  and using the chiral operator ". Why are you thinking that both definitions are not isomorphic to each other and how can it be shown that both will give the same result (without explicit calculation for a corresponding system)?

Comment: But if there are not equivalent (which I called isomorphic) why do you expect them to give the same result ? A topological invariant is designed to work with some symmetries. Somehow, it doesn't work if one of these symmetries is broken. So one of your $\nu$'s works for system without symmetry (and it is usually called a winding number), and the second one works for systems with time-reversal invariant (this one has doublet states due to Kramers degeneracy) and chiral symmetry (making doublet at opposite energy).

Comment: If you apply the first definition to systems with time-reversal and chiral symmetries, you will get zero, whereas you will get a non-zero integer for systems with chiral and time reversal symmetries. To show that the $\nu$'s are integer is a hard mathematical question (at least I do not understand the proof). To show they define cohomology classes of the differentiable Hermitian bundles is not amazingly difficult (I recommend a book by Chern, Lectures on Differential Geometry). In any case your two $\nu$'s ARE NOT THE SAME THING and will never give you the same result for a given system !!!

Comment: Thanks, now I understood the argument by Bernevig. So the first definition will be everytime zero but only for even dimension.

Comment: Furthermore, it would be nice to understand the relation of the second Definition and the corresponding characteristic class.